# Multiplying 2 values in nested array then push to a new array - JavaScript Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array and I am trying to multiply two values `qty` and `packageQuantity`, creating a new array with the result set to the `units` key.

The trouble is I have a complex nested array and can't workout how to create a new array!

I have figured out how to do the multiplication, however I can't figure out how to push the values to a new array.

I am using Vue, and want to change the values live if possible.

**How can I do the multiplication, creating a new array putting the result in the units key?**

*To clarify, I want to create a new array putting the new result in whilst adding the old values in too. See below.*

Thanks so much in advance!

Here is my current array:

```
data: () => ({
sites: [

  {
    sku: "10001",
    values: [
      {
        variationName: { name: "Unpackaged", qty: 1 },
        units: '',
        packageQuantity: '2'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    sku: "10002",
    values: [
      {
        variationName: { name: "2 Pack", qty: 2 },
        units: '',
        packageQuantity: '3'
      },
      {
        variationName: { name: "4 Pack", qty: 4 },
        units: '',
        packageQuantity: '1'
      }
    ]
  }
    ]
})
```

Here is what I want my output to be:

```
sites: [

  {
    sku: "10001",
    values: [
      {
        variationName: { name: "Unpackaged", qty: 1 },
        units: '2', // 1 * 2
        packageQuantity: '2'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    sku: "10002",
    values: [
      {
        variationName: { name: "2 Pack", qty: 2 },
        units: '6', // 2 * 3
        packageQuantity: '3'
      },
      {
        variationName: { name: "4 Pack", qty: 4 },
        units: '4', // 1 * 4
        packageQuantity: '1'
      }
    ]
  }
    ]
```

Here is my calculation:

```
 sites.forEach(
  (innerArray) => innerArray.values.forEach(
   (item => console.log(item.variationName.qty * item.units))
  )
 )
```

Comment: Is `units` supposed to be an integer? They appear to be all empty strings in your example. Also, should the result be a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)?

Comment: Apologies, yes! I've updated the example.

Comment: The unit value is still an empyt string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           let newData=[]; 
            let sites = [

                {
                    sku: "10001",
                    values: [{
                        variationName: {
                            name: "Unpackaged",
                            qty: 1
                        },
                        units: '',
                        packageQuantity: '2'
                    }]
                },
                {
                    sku: "10002",
                    values: [{
                            variationName: {
                                name: "2 Pack",
                                qty: 2
                            },
                            units: '',
                            packageQuantity: '3'
                        },
                        {
                            variationName: {
                                name: "4 Pack",
                                qty: 4
                            },
                            units: '',
                            packageQuantity: '1'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
                let iData = sites[i].values;
                for (let j = 0; j < iData.length; j++) {
                    iData[j].units = parseInt(iData[j].packageQuantity) * parseInt(iData[j].variationName.qty);
                }

            }
             newData.push(sites);
```

Output

```
    newData: [
            {
                sku: "10001",
                values: [{
                    variationName: {
                        name: "Unpackaged",
                        qty: 1
                    },
                    units: 2, 
                    packageQuantity: '2'
                }]
            },
            {
                sku: "10002",
                values: [{
                        variationName: {
                            name: "2 Pack",
                            qty: 2
                        },
                        units: 6,
                        packageQuantity: '3'
                    },
                    {
                        variationName: {
                            name: "4 Pack",
                            qty: 4
                        },
                        units: 4, 
                        packageQuantity: '1'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take what you've already done and assign it to `item.units`. But you have to remember to convert the values to integers before the multiplication. You'll also have to convert the result back to a string if you need it as a string. Here's how you would do it if all values were numbers:

```
 sites.forEach(
    (innerArray) => innerArray.values.forEach(item => { 
       item.units = item.variationName.qty * item.units; 
    })
 )
```

It might be worth noting that what you've called `innerArray` isn't really an array and actually an object so you might want to name it better for clarity's sake.

Comment: Thanks! How can I implement the push. If I do `this.testArray.push({
            packageQty: item.variationName.qty * item.units
          });` in place of `item.units = item.variationName.qty * item.units;` I get a loop of many values! Cheers!

Comment: @tbowden Are you trying to take the product of those values, put it into an array with one object and then set `units` to the array? Or, is there another array outside this `forEach` that you are trying to build with objects?

Comment: Not exactly. I would like to create a new array called testArray and basically recreate it, adding the product into a key called packageQuantity. Thanks!

Comment: @tbowden Ok. I think I understand what you want now. For that, I would recommend using `Array.reduce`. Unfortunately I can't show you my solution right now because of time, but I'd be happy to make a new answer if someone else doesn't before I come back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do:

```
const datum = {
  sites: [

    {
      sku: "10001",
      values: [
        {
          variationName: { name: "Unpackaged", qty: 1 },
          units: 5,
          packageQuantity: ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      sku: "10002",
      values: [
        {
          variationName: { name: "2 Pack", qty: 2 },
          units: 3,
        },
        {
          variationName: { name: "4 Pack", qty: 4 },
          units: 6,
          packageQuantity: ""
        }
      ]
    }
      ]
  };

const qtyCalculated = datum && datum.sites && datum.sites.reduce((acc, site) => {
  if (!acc["sku"]) {
    acc["sku"] = [];
  }
  acc["sku"].push(site.sku);
  if (!acc["qty"]) {
    acc["qty"] = [];
  }
  acc["qty"].push(...site.values && site.values.reduce((valueAcc, valueItem) => {
    valueAcc.push(valueItem.variationName.qty * parseInt(valueItem.units, 10));
    return valueAcc;
  }, []));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(qtyCalculated);
```

You can add the name and have the quantity calculated individually for every value item too. I have declared the units a number in the datum. If you are using a string, use the `parseInt` as above.